# Plotly.io doesn't see the psutil package even though it's installed

Tags: python, plotly, psutil, plotly-python

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer

import os

if not os.path.exists("images"):
    os.mkdir("images")

# import orca


import plotly.io as pio
pio.orca.config.executable = '/path/to/orca'
pio.orca.ensure_server()

import psutil
```

To which I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-6e2b31e44303> in <module>
     25 import plotly.io as pio
     26 pio.orca.config.executable = '/path/to/orca'
---> 27 pio.orca.ensure_server()
     28 
     29 import psutil

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py in ensure_server()
   1368 Install using conda:
   1369     $ conda install psutil
-> 1370 """
   1371         )
   1372 

ValueError: Image generation requires the psutil package.

Install using pip:
    $ pip install psutil

Install using conda:
    $ conda install psutil
```

The package is installed, I reinstalled it just in case as well but keep getting the error.

The end goal is to be able to safe plotly generated images automatically with `fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")`

Comment: You are likely installing the package in a different environment. Are you running the code in a conda virtual env?

Comment: Should be the same, all other packages were installed the same way:
`% python3 -m pip install psutil==5.4.8 --user`

Comment: But are you running the code in a virtual environment?

Comment: Did you solve it? It's happening to me too

Comment: unfortunately, no. Ended up with a manual saving. Because once I somehow solved `import psutil` it started requesting `requests` which I have already had.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the plotly figure as image.

What worked for me was to install `kaleido`and then use the kaleido engine
e.g.

pip install Kaleido
plotly.io.write_image(fig, 'fig1.jpeg', format='jpeg',validate=False, engine='kaleido')

see the following question/answer too:
[How to save plotly express plot into a html or static image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815797/how-to-save-plotly-express-plot-into-a-html-or-static-image-file)